# Bidimensional Array Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to animate some circle in my page, in order to do that, i'm trying to store that circle in a matrix.

```
var elementWidth = parseInt($('#svg').width()); //Take container element's width
var circleRadius = parseInt(elementWidth/10); //Calculate radius and the distance from a circle to another
var circleMatrix = [[]]; //The 2d matrix
var s = Snap("#svg"); //Initialize Snap (it's a svg framework)
var x,y=0; //My index

for(var i=0; i<=elementWidth; i+=circleRadius){
  x=0;
  for(var m=0; m<=elementWidth; m+=circleRadius){
    console.log("y("+y+"): "+i+" x("+x+"): "+m);
    circleMatrix[y][x] = s.circle(m,i,50);
    x++;
  }
  y++;
}
```

The code is really easy and a i can't understand why it returns this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: `[[]]` doesn't really make any sense. Javascript doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Oliver: *That* part makes sense: That's an array with one entry, which is an empty array.

Comment: @Oliver How would you declare an array with an array as its zeroth element? How does "Javascript not work like that"?

Comment: `circleMatrix[1]` is undefined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I suppose you're right. It's more like its not doing what he thinks it is doing.

Comment: @Oliver Mh, i didn't know that... I'm just trying to put an array into another one. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't really have two-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays instead.

This line:

```
var circleMatrix = [[]]; //The 2d matrix
```

creates an array with **one** entry: A blank array. So `circleMatrix[1]` (for instance) is `undefined`.

You'll have to add arrays at all of the positions in the outer array for which you need them. One way to do that would be to add:

```
if (!circleMatrix[y]) {
    circleMatrix[y] = [];
}
```

just before this line:

```
circleMatrix[y][x] = s.circle(m,i,50);
```

E.g.:

```
var elementWidth = parseInt($('#svg').width()); //Take container element's width
var circleRadius = parseInt(elementWidth/10); //Calculate radius and the distance from a circle to another
var circleMatrix = [];                      // *** Changed
var s = Snap("#svg"); //Initialize Snap (it's a svg framework)
var x,y=0; //My index

for(var i=0; i<=elementWidth; i+=circleRadius){
  x=0;
  for(var m=0; m<=elementWidth; m+=circleRadius){
    console.log("y("+y+"): "+i+" x("+x+"): "+m);
    if (!circleMatrix[y]) {                 // *** Added
        circleMatrix[y] = [];               // *** Added
    }                                       // *** Added
    circleMatrix[y][x] = s.circle(m,i,50);
    x++;
  }
  y++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a 2D matrix in JavaScript, you have to do something like the following:

```
var circleMatrix = [[],[],[]];
```

You have to know ahead of time what one dimension is, or plan to create each "row" as you iterate the outer loop.